# Opencv Mat access violation

Tags: c++, opencv

While running the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
   for(int j = 0; j < result[i].size(); ++j) {
     if(anchor_map->at<float>(i, j) > 0) {
     }
   }
}
```

With the size of result.size() 1200 and result[i].size() being 1600 over the board, the locks the range of i and j in place as the anchor_map.size() is [1600 x 1200].

The problem is that every time at i = 1197, j = 1436 it cuts out with an access violation, while anchor_map is set to zeroes at the start with at the right pixel a one where an anchor is located.

Is made in Visual Studio 12 on windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Does `anchor_map` store floats to begin with?

Comment: It's an IplImage *anchor_map = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(gray), 8, 1); converted to a Mat for easier access, the anchor_map is set with cvSet2D(anchor_map, y, x, Scalar(255));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using namespace cv;
void main (void)
{
    Mat anchor_map(1200,1600,CV_8UC1);

    for(int i = 0; i < anchor_map.rows; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < anchor_map.cols; ++j) {
            if(anchor_map.at<unsigned char>(i, j) > 0) {
            }
        }
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: This worked, do you know the reason why it only throws an error at a specific value in the Matrix?

Comment: Not completely understand you question. Which specific value do you mean? Previous code was not working because matrix element type is CV_8U that means unsigned char you try access them as float which is CV_32F element type. Indexing uses size of matrix element for compute memory address of element.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the CV_8U / CV_32F difference, but my question was, as it's a for loop and it doesn't crash till i = 1197 and j = 1436 while I'm 100% sure that the values before that are also set to similar values as i = 1197/j = 1436 but there is no error/crash

Comment: I have changed my answer, I have checked it and it works perfect.